# Filebeat does not complete on close_eof + --once

Tags: filebeat, elk

Using filebeat 7.5.2:

I'm using a filebeat configuration with close_eof enabled and I run filebeat with the flag --once. I can see the harvester reaching eof but the filebeat keeps going.

Flebeat conf:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  close_eof: true
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - "${LOGS_PATH}"
  scan_frequency: 1s
  fields: {
    machine: "${HOST}"
  }


output.logstash:
  hosts: ["192.168.41.6:5044"]
  bulk_max_size: 1024
  timeout: 30s
  pipelining: 1
  workers: 1
```

And I run it using:

```
filebeat run --once -v -c "PATH TO CONF..."
```

And some logs from the filebeat instance:

```
...
    2020-02-04T18:30:16.950Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:297    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.5.2
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.059Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/module.go:97   Beat name: logstash
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.167Z        WARN    beater/filebeat.go:152  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch out
    put is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.168Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:429    filebeat start running.
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.168Z        INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.168Z        INFO    registrar/migrate.go:104        No registry home found. Create: /tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/data/registry/filebeat
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.179Z        INFO    registrar/migrate.go:112        Initialize registry meta file
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.192Z        INFO    registrar/registrar.go:108      No registry file found under: /tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/data/registry/filebeat/data.json. Creating a new re
    gistry file.
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.193Z        INFO    registrar/registrar.go:145      Loading registrar data from /tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/data/registry/filebeat/data.json
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.193Z        INFO    registrar/registrar.go:152      States Loaded from registrar: 0
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.193Z        WARN    beater/filebeat.go:368  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch out
    put is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.193Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:72   Loading Inputs: 1
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.194Z        INFO    log/input.go:152        Configured paths: [/tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/*.log]
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.206Z        INFO    input/input.go:114      Starting input of type: log; ID: 13918413832820009056 
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.225Z        INFO    input/input.go:167      Stopping Input: 13918413832820009056
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.225Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:106  Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.225Z        INFO    log/harvester.go:251    Harvester started for file: /tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/dcbgw-20200124080032_darkblue.log
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.231Z        INFO    beater/filebeat.go:384  Running filebeat once. Waiting for completion ...
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.231Z        INFO    beater/filebeat.go:386  All data collection completed. Shutting down.
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.231Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:139  Stopping Crawler
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.231Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:149  Stopping 1 inputs
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.258Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://192.168.41.6:5044))
    2020-02-04T18:30:17.296Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:105  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://192.168.41.6:5044)) established

    ... Only metrics here ...

    2020-02-04T18:35:55.686Z        INFO    log/harvester.go:274    End of file reached: /tmp/tmp.BXJtfiaEzb/dcbgw-20200124080032_darkblue.log. Closing because close_eof is enabled.
    2020-02-04T18:35:55.686Z        INFO    crawler/crawler.go:165  Crawler stopped
... MORE METRICS ...
    2020-02-04T18:36:26.609Z        ERROR   logstash/async.go:256   Failed to publish events caused by: read tcp 192.168.41.6:49662->192.168.41.6:5044: i/o timeout
    2020-02-04T18:36:26.621Z        ERROR   logstash/async.go:256   Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
    2020-02-04T18:36:28.520Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:121  Failed to publish events: client is not connected
    2020-02-04T18:36:28.520Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://192.168.41.6:5044))
    2020-02-04T18:36:28.521Z        INFO    pipeline/output.go:105  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://192.168.41.6:5044)) established

... MORE METRICS ...
```

From this I'm outputing this to Logstash 7.5.2 running in the same Ubuntu 18 VM. Running Logstash with log level trace does not output any error.